# How do I require booleans in Play forms?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, boolean, require

I'm using Play 2.1.0. I'm trying create an Action that accepts a POST request and requires that a boolean be required in the request body. What's happening now is that even if I don't supply the param the Action gets a false value. Test code:

```
// /post/boolean/single routes to this method
def postTestBooleanSingle = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = Form("flag" -> boolean)
    form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors =>
            BadRequest(formWithErrors.errors map (fe => fe.key + ": " + fe.message) mkString ", "),
        flag => Ok(f"got $flag%b")
    )
}

// /post/num/single routes to this method
def postTestNumSingle = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = Form("num" -> number)
    form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => 
            BadRequest(formWithErrors.errors map (fe => fe.key + ": " + fe.message) mkString ", "),
        num => Ok(f"got $num%d")
    )
}

$ curl -XPOST -d "num=42" http://localhost:9000/post/num/single
got 42
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9000/post/num/single
num: error.required // didn't provide num so i get an error
$ curl -XPOST -d "flag=true" http://localhost:9000/post/boolean/single
got true
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9000/post/boolean/single
got false // ???
```

How do I require a boolean parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the Form mapping for the Boolean type appears to default to false in the absence of any parameters.

Here's the snippet responsible from Format.scala in the play source:

```
/**
 * Default formatter for the `Boolean` type.
 */
implicit def booleanFormat: Formatter[Boolean] = new Formatter[Boolean] {

  override val format = Some(("format.boolean", Nil))

  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
    Right(data.get(key).getOrElse("false")).right.flatMap {
      case "true" => Right(true)
      case "false" => Right(false)
      case _ => Left(Seq(FormError(key, "error.boolean", Nil)))
    }
  }

  def unbind(key: String, value: Boolean) = Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```

The important part here is the `data.get(key).getOrElse("false")`. In the absence of any input, it defaults booleans to false. You'll want to create a custom formatter and use that do define a custom binding for booleans.

I'll leave it to you to put these in good places in your code base, but the pieces of your puzzle should look something like this:

```
// This is the custom formatter to support your custom mapping.
import play.api.data.format.Formatter
implicit def requiredBooleanFormatter: Formatter[Boolean] = new Formatter[Boolean] {

  override val format = Some(("format.boolean", Nil))

  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
    Right(data.get(key).getOrElse("")).right.flatMap {
      case "true" => Right(true)
      case "false" => Right(false)
      case _ => Left(Seq(FormError(key, "error.boolean", Nil)))
    }
  }

  def unbind(key: String, value: Boolean) = Map(key -> value.toString)
}

// This is your custom mapping to be used in the form
import play.api.data.Forms
val requiredBoolean: Mapping[Boolean] = Forms.of[Boolean](requiredBooleanFormatter)
```

Notice the change from `.getOrElse("false")` to `.getOrElse("")`. The code is almost the same, but we're now pushing empty values to the error catcher instead of making them take a `false` value. (Note: I explicitly specify `requiredBooleanFormatter` in this example for clarity, but since `requiredBooleanFormatter` is implicit and in scope, you don't have to.)

Now you can just use `requiredBoolean` instead of `boolean` in your forms to require that the param is explicitly set in the request.